# Java OpenCV Not Detecting Contours Properly

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv to detect contours of cards scanned against a white background. However, I'm running into an issue where it seems to just be detecting the whole image as 1 contour. I'm completely stumped on what I can tweak at this point. I've tried ImgProc.RETR_LIST but that returns 42k contours.

**Code:**

```
    public void convert() throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Load the image file
        // temp
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:input_image.png");
        // temp change to inputstream
        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());

        // Convert the image to grayscale
        Mat grayImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(image, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        // Apply a threshold to convert the image to black and white
        Mat thresholdImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.threshold(grayImage, thresholdImage, 242, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("thresh.png", thresholdImage);

        // Find contours in the thresholded image
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours(thresholdImage, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        // Set the amount of empty space to add around the cropped image
        int emptySpace = 20;

        // Loop over the contours
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
            MatOfPoint contour = contours.get(i);

            // Find the bounding box of the contour
            Rect boundingRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour);

            // Crop the rectangle from the original image using the bounding box coordinates
            Mat rect = new Mat(image, boundingRect);

            // Straighten the rectangle
            RotatedRect rotatedRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray()));
            double angle = rotatedRect.angle;
            if (rotatedRect.size.width > rotatedRect.size.height) {
                angle += 90;
            }
            Mat rotationMatrix = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(rotatedRect.center, angle, 1.0);
            Mat rotatedRectMat = new Mat();
            Imgproc.warpAffine(rect, rotatedRectMat, rotationMatrix, rect.size());

            // Add empty space around the cropped image
            Mat rectWithBorder = new Mat();
            Core.copyMakeBorder(rotatedRectMat, rectWithBorder, emptySpace, emptySpace, emptySpace, emptySpace, Core.BORDER_CONSTANT, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

            // Save the rectangle with border as a separate image file
            Imgcodecs.imwrite(String.format("output_image_%d.png", i), rectWithBorder);

        }
    }
```

**Input Image**:

[image]

**Generated Threshold:**

[image]

**Output Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the whole image is detected as one contour is that `findContours` finds white contours (not black contours), and the entire image after threshold is a large white contour.

Use `Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV` for inverting black and white:

```
Imgproc.threshold(grayImage, thresholdImage, 242, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

---

Other issues:

- We may ignore small contours - considered to be noise:

  ```
   double contour_area = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
   if (contour_area < min_contour_area) {
       continue;
   }
  ```
- Add white padding before `warpAffine` - required because `warpAffine` may add black margins (think of 45 degrees rotation for example):

  ```
   Mat rect = new Mat(image, boundingRect);
   rect = rect.clone(); //Create a clone of the cropped rectangle (required because copyMakeBorder refers to the large image).
   Mat rectWithBorder = new Mat();
   Core.copyMakeBorder(rect, rectWithBorder, emptySpace*2, emptySpace*2, emptySpace*2, emptySpace*2, Core.BORDER_CONSTANT, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
  ```
- Rotate around the center of the cropped rectangle (not around `rotatedRect.center`):

  ```
   Point rect_center = new Point((rectWithBorder.cols()-1.0)/2, (rectWithBorder.rows()-1.0)/2);
   Mat rotationMatrix = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(rect_center, angle, 1.0);  
   Mat rotatedRectMat = new Mat();
   Imgproc.warpAffine(rectWithBorder, rotatedRectMat, rotationMatrix, rectWithBorder.size());
  ```
- Remove the extra margins after `warpAffine`:

  ```
   Rect boundingRect2 = new Rect(emptySpace, emptySpace, rotatedRectMat.cols()-emptySpace*2, rotatedRectMat.rows()-emptySpace*2);
   Mat rectWithBorder2 = new Mat(rotatedRectMat, boundingRect2);
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
package myproject;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.RotatedRect;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Sample {
    

static { System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }


  
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Load the image file
    // temp
    //File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:input_image.png");
    final String image_file_name = "input_image.png";
    
    // temp change to inputstream
    Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(image_file_name);

    // Convert the image to grayscale
    Mat grayImage = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // Apply a threshold to convert the image to black and white
    Mat thresholdImage = new Mat();
    //Imgproc.threshold(grayImage, thresholdImage, 242, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    Imgproc.threshold(grayImage, thresholdImage, 242, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite("thresh.png", thresholdImage);

    // Find contours in the thresholded image
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(thresholdImage, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // Set the amount of empty space to add around the cropped image
    int emptySpace = 20;
    
    double min_contour_area = 10000.0;  //Area threshold - ignore small contours with area less than 10000 (assume noise)

    // Loop over the contours
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        MatOfPoint contour = contours.get(i);
        
        double contour_area = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
        
        if (contour_area < min_contour_area) {
            continue;   //Ignore small contours with area less than min_contour_area (assume noise)
        }

        // Find the bounding box of the contour
        Rect boundingRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour);

        // Crop the rectangle from the original image using the bounding box coordinates
        Mat rect = new Mat(image, boundingRect);
        rect = rect.clone(); //Create a clone of the cropped rectangle (required because copyMakeBorder refers to the large image). 
        
        //Imgcodecs.imwrite("rect.png", rect); //Save rect for testing

        // Straighten the rectangle
        RotatedRect rotatedRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray()));
        double angle = rotatedRect.angle;
        if (rotatedRect.size.width > rotatedRect.size.height) {
            angle += 90;
        }
               
        // Add empty space around the rect - add larger padding before rotation because warpAffine may add black margins
        Mat rectWithBorder = new Mat();
        Core.copyMakeBorder(rect, rectWithBorder, emptySpace*2, emptySpace*2, emptySpace*2, emptySpace*2, Core.BORDER_CONSTANT, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
        
        //Imgcodecs.imwrite("rectWithBorder.png", rectWithBorder); //Save rectWithBorder for testing
        
        //Mat rotationMatrix = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(rotatedRect.center, angle, 1.0);  
        Point rect_center = new Point((rectWithBorder.cols()-1.0)/2, (rectWithBorder.rows()-1.0)/2);
        Mat rotationMatrix = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(rect_center, angle, 1.0);  //Rotate around the center of rect.
        Mat rotatedRectMat = new Mat();
        Imgproc.warpAffine(rectWithBorder, rotatedRectMat, rotationMatrix, rectWithBorder.size());
        
        //Imgcodecs.imwrite("rotatedRectMat.png", rotatedRectMat); //Save rotatedRectMat for testing
        
        //Crop the center of rotatedRectMat (remove the extra emptySpace padding from each side).
        Rect boundingRect2 = new Rect(emptySpace, emptySpace, rotatedRectMat.cols()-emptySpace*2, rotatedRectMat.rows()-emptySpace*2);
        Mat rectWithBorder2 = new Mat(rotatedRectMat, boundingRect2);


        // Save the rectangle with border as a separate image file
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(String.format("output_image_%d.png", i), rectWithBorder2);
    }
}

}
```

---

Result:
[image]  [image]  [image]

[image]  [image]  [image]

[image]  [image]  [image]

Comment: I'm beyond grateful for this! Thank you for going above and beyond in your answer.